# S3 list versioned objects

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am using the following syntax to list versions in s3 using boto3.

```
object_versions = s3.list_object_versions(Bucket=bucket_name)
```

Strangely, it is not listing the objects with only one version left. Please see the screenshot below, i can see the objects on the aws console but i can't get them from my boto3 script.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps an object with only one version is not classified as a 'versioned' object?

Comment: not sure. It doesn't even appear when i use list_objects_v2.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. The list object api of boto3 only lists limited results (~1000 objects).
To go beyond you may need to use paginator.

Here is a sample code, you can ignore the unwanted lines.

```
import boto3


s3 = boto3.client('s3')

paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_object_versions')
pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket='bucket_name', Prefix='')

for page in pages:
    for obj in page['Versions']:
            print(obj['Key'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import boto3

# Create an S3 client
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

# Specify the bucket name
bucket_name = 'your_bucket_name'

# List all versions of objects in the bucket
object_versions = s3.list_object_versions(Bucket=bucket_name)

# Print information about each version (including delete markers)
for version in object_versions.get('Versions', []):
    print(f"Key: {version['Key']}, VersionId: {version['VersionId']}, IsDeleteMarker: False")

# Print information about each delete marker (if any)
for delete_marker in object_versions.get('DeleteMarkers', []):
    print(f"Key: {delete_marker['Key']}, VersionId: {delete_marker['VersionId']}, IsDeleteMarker: True")
```

This code will print information about all versions, including both versioned objects and their delete markers.

Comment: No luck with this. It doesn't bring the objects shown in the screenshot.